# Makefile issue with calling another shell file for make

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I have created a parent makefile. as below:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash

HOMEDIR = $(shell pwd)

PKGNAM = PARAMETIS

override VERSION = 4.0.3
YESDIR = $(shell echo $(@:install-%=%) | tr A-Z a-z)
NODIR = $(shell echo $(@:clean-%=%) | tr A-Z a-z)


install:
    $(MAKE) install-$(VERSION)

install-%:
    @if [ ! -e $(YESDIR) ]; then \
        echo "Library $(PKGNAM) Version=$(YESDIR) does not exist"; \
    elif [ -e $(YESDIR)/Install.sh ]; then \
        echo "Installing $(PKGNAM) version=$(YESDIR)" ; \
        cd $(YESDIR) ;\
        $(SHELL) Install.sh $(HOMEDIR) 1 ;\
    elif [ -e $(YESDIR)/Makefile ]; then \
        cd $(YESDIR); \
        $(MAKE); \
    else \
        echo "Installation instruction for $(@:install-%=%) Version=$(YESDIR) does not exist"; \
    fi;

clean:
    @$(MAKE) clean-$(VERSION)

clean-%:
    @if [! -e ${NODIR} ]; then ;\
        echo "Library does not exist $(PKGNAM) version=$(NODIR)" ; \
    else \
        cd $(NODIR) ;\
        echo "Installing $(PKGNAM) version=$(NODIR)" ; \
        $(SHELL) Install.sh $(HOMEDIR) 0 ;\
    fi;
```

This makefile calls different bash files inside each version of the libraries directories to build them, the bash files can successfully build each library if I call it from the terminal, tho when I call them from my make file using,

> make install

after it executes the install.sh and build the library, I get this error that

> No rule to make target 'w'.  Stop.

any idea why it happens and how can I get rid of it ?

HERE is the bash file if it helps:

```
if (test $2 = 1) then
    make --silent -f Makefile config prefix=$1/exec
    make --silent -f Makefile
    make --silent -f Makefile install
elif (test $2 = 0) then
    make --silent -f Makefile clean
fi
```

Thanks

Comment: The commands to make a target have to be indented.

Comment: They are in the makefile, I don;t know how to indent them here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Paste the properly indented code, mark it with the mouse, type Ctl-k.

Comment: formatted correctly now, any solution ?

Comment: Why do you have the `@`s in there? If you're trying to debug something, suppressing output is making it needlessly hard.

Comment: BTW, `[! -e ${NODIR} ]` is definitely wrong syntax-wise; the `!` needs to be a separate word; otherwise, it's looking for a command named `[!`, which doesn't exist. And that's ignoring the quoting bugs...

Comment: speaking of quoting bugs, though -- let's walk through how things parse. `[ -e ${empty} ]` doesn't parse to `[ -e "" ]`, it parses to `[ -e ]`. Now, would you guess that `[ -e ]` is false? You'd be wrong! It's *true*, because it's equivalent to `[ -n -e ]`; it's checking if the string `"-e"` is empty or not.

Comment: that said, I don't do support for Make -- shell is complicated enough before using awful string-concatenation approaches to try to generate scripts -- so take all the above with a heaping amount of salt.

Comment: I agree, you need to remove the initial `@` so you can actually see what command is being invoked.  Also, you can modify your bash script to add `set -x` at the front and it will print out the commands that _it_ is running.  Based on what's here it's hard to know what's happening.

Comment: @aaramoon the problem is probably in `4.0.3/Makefile` that you are not providing

Comment: @ComeRaczy : No, it runs the install.sh file, does not really go into the one with makefile, and Makefile is also in the directory

Comment: @MadScientist: I think it has something to do with going into the directory to call the install.sh, similar error has been reported for a different case here :
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/solaris-opensolaris-20/no-rule-to-make-target-%60w'-stop-4175440156/

Comment: @aaramoon I believe that you should re-read carefully the code or double check what `make` says after enabling the traces. With the `Makefile` and `Install.sh` that you provided (assuming that is in `4.0.3`), there is a `cd 4.0.3` before invoking `Install.sh` and `Install.sh` uses the Makefile in the current directory (hence `4.0.3/Makefile`)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by calling other Makefiles using -C in the library's makefile called in the Install.sh. This sets the MAKEFLAGS to w automatically. unfortunately, the developers of the library has made mistake in calling the makefiles as below:

> $(MAKE) -C $(SUBDIR) $@ $(MAKEFLAGS)

when the makefile is called from another makefile, this MAKEFLAGS are set to w, but in the bash called from the terminal they are empty. because developers have forgotten to add MAKEFLAGS= before the flags, it assumes that w is another target and because it is not defined it generates the error, I menotiond.

I solved the issue by changing their makefile as below:

> $(MAKE) -c $(SUBDIR) $@ MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)

and now everything works as expected.